# Tricky excel trick - randomize value between 2-3 - apply to many products with many rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of thousands of product that already have a price to it. My task is to come up with a "reference price" for my products. And this needs to be a random multiplier between 2-3 for all products.

Example:

Product A costs $10, reference price $24
Product B costs $5, reference prise $13
etc etc etc.

Now, my problem is that each product is not a single row, in face each product consists of 1-20 rows (each product has variants, like color, size etc, but they all cost the sam) Their reference price must be the same.

I found out how to randomize a number between 2-3 using "=RAND()*1+2". But now, it will be a different price for all variants.

So if Product A that costs $10 has 20 variants, this means every variant will be given a randomized "reference price". I need them all to have the same randomized value. With thousands of products, i need to be able to do this in one go with some commands.

[image]

here is a link to an example: https://ibb.co/6rRV98V

i need the green and blue values to be the same values.

How do I do this?

Very helpful for any help! :)

/Nisse

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: uhm, did you see my post, picture and explanation?

Comment: Yes, I did. You don't show that you have tried anything at all.

Comment: but i have showed you/explained how far i got so far.  

the last step is to difficult for me (and for you as well i assume). My question is hard to google (i think). But yes, i have asked google for 1 hour or so. :)

Answer (score 0):

Build a helper table with a unique list of your products, their original price and calculate the variance price.

Then use a lookup formula (XLookup, VLookup, Index/Match) to pull the variance price from the helper table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,INDEX($C$2:$C$14,MATCH(A2,$A$2:A2,0)),B2*(RAND()+2))
```

[image]

Comment: got it working i think: =MEDIAN(0, MOD(48271*A5,2^31-1)/(2^31-1), 1)+1.5

:D

Comment: Are you talking about random multiplier? Or what?